# A ruby method that takes a block and calls that block

Tags: ruby

In an application of mine, I have some code that looks like this:

```
if is_translation?
  @booking.enable_dirty_associations do                                           
    booking_update
  end
else
  booking_update
end
```

I would like it instead to look like this:

```
is_translation? ? @booking.enable_dirty_associations : func do
  booking_update
end
```

Where `func` is the method that takes the block and just executes it.

Is there a built in Ruby method, or perhaps a combinator function that does this?

Comment: is the block being passed in?  are you creating it in some way? based on what you have provided you don't need a block, you could just do: "is_translation? ? @booking.enable_dirty_associations : booking_update" and have "booking_update" be a method on the instance you are working in.  need some more info to really help out.

Comment: booking_update is a method on the instance I'm working on yes. enable_dirty_associations I believe only takes a block, all I want to do in that block is call booking_update.

Comment: As an example the prototype js library provide Prototype.K http://api.prototypejs.org/Prototype/K/ a function that returns its arguments untouched. I guess what I am looking for is something along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty easy to write func() for yourself:

```
def func
  yield
end
```

Unfortunately, however, your idea won't work, the block will only apply to `func`, not the first call. The only way I can think of to get close to what you want is to define the block as a proc and pass it manually:

```
block = Proc.new { booking_update }

is_translation? ? @booking.enable_dirty_associations(&block) : block.call
```

This does have the advantage of not needing the `func()` method.

Comment: I thought that the syntax might be slightly off there. I was hoping I could do something like `(is_translation? ?@booking.enable_dirty_associations : func) do booking_update end`
I was aware of the Proc.new method, but was looking for something more elegant